# Daily usage time in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, epoch

I am trying to achieve the Sum of Hours spent per day, where my mysql database has multiple logging records of every activity they perform (e.g; login, view, update, logout). What i am trying to do is SELECT (all records of a particular day) and find the difference in epoch time between the first and last entry giving me the 'Time Spent' for that period. Later add it by Month etc.

Database schema;

id, userid, time, action

[image: database screenshot]

**I can select the first and last entry from the query below:

**
SELECT 
*(SELECT time FROM log WHERE time(myDate) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY time LIMIT 1) as 'first',
(SELECT column FROM table WHERE time(myDate) = DATE(NOW()) ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1) as 'last'*

But i am guessing a cross join or SUM for all these have to happen. Some guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: From your screenshot your time field looks like it's just a plain integer.  Date/Time functions will not work with plain integers, they require a temporal datatype such as TIMESTAMP or DATETIME

Comment: its epoch time Gordon..

Comment: The database doesn't know that, as far as it's concerned if you've not specified a column as DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, etc then it's just a number.